# Rotation of Child

Tags: vertex-groups, parent, soft-body

i have made this soft body with some blobs parented to vertex, The problem is as the soft body moves, the blobs are rotating, like copying the parent rotation to their local rotation.
The child object is keeping looking up:

[image]

[image]

I have tried constrains, but no luck

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 0 dimensional objects, vertices do not really have rotation in the same way that other objects do.

When encountering problems like this, it's usually helpful to reduce the problem to simpler examples.  In this case, just use two cubes and vertex parent one cube to a vertex of the other cube.  Now try rotating the parent.  Notice how you can't get the child cube to change orientation?

If you need your children to acquire some kind of orientation, you need to provide them additional information.  In your case, consider giving your blobs a damped track constraint to a a bone or empty located at the location of your parent object.  This will keep the blobs facing outward.

At least, that's the easy version, but it's still flawed because you're leaving an axis of rotation undefined.  The ideal way to do this is to follow the damped track with a locked track to a single vertex vertex group to fully specify the orientation.  When quality is important enough to do this, you might as well specify the target of the damped-track on a per-vertex basis with single vertex vertex groups as well, so that your blobs will orient properly with local soft body surface deformations.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be expected: being a soft object, and having child blobs, the blobs inertia kicks in when you rotate the soft object, because their bodies suffer from lower acceleration than the parent.
If you don't want the blobs to 'fall behind' you need to create a 'harder' link between them and the parent, or make them more rigid.

Comment: Like?I created an empty, that gives the rotation, I also tried copy rotation but changed the origin, to the mass origin.Its not perfect, but it somehow works better